# Prove that the map $c:{\mathbb {T}}^{3}=S^{1}\times S^{1}\times S^{1}\setminus\ \Delta\longrightarrow \{\pm 1\}$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

Prove that the map $c:{\mathbb  {T}}^{3}=S^{1}\times S^{1}\times S^{1}\setminus \Delta\longrightarrow \{\pm 1\}$ is continuous where $\Delta$ is the diagonal 
$\Delta=\{(g_i,g_j,g_k)\}$ for $i=j$ or $j=k$ or $i=k$ and $c$ has the following properties:

1)($\textit{Left-Invarianc}$): $c(ag_1,ag_2,ag_3)=c(g_1,g_2,g_3)$ for all $a,g_1,g_2,g_3\in S^1$ with $g_i\ne g_j$ for any $i$ and $j$

2)($\textit{Co-cycle condition}$): $c(g_1,g_2,g_3)-c(g_1,g_2,g_4)+c(g_1,g_3,g_4)-c(g_2,g_3,g_4)=0$ for all $g_1,g_2,g_3,g_4\in S^1$ with $g_i\ne g_j$ for any $i$ and $j$

These two conditions basically tells us that there is a certain order on circle which is left-invariant.

I want to prove or disprove the continuity of $c$ where $\{\pm 1\}$ is given discrete topology. We see that $\mathbb{T}^{3}=S^{1}\times S^{1}\times S^{1}$ is a [three dimensional torus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-torus) and not much of its topological facts are given in the wiki article. Please suggest where should I start.

EDIT: Image after Paul Plummer's comment
[image]

Comment: Try to check what the connected components of $\mathbb T^3 \setminus \Delta$ are.

Comment: @Levi How exactly? This three torus blows my mind when I try to visualize.

Comment: When you say that "prove that **the** map $c$..." Did you mean "prove that any map $c$... With the following properties..." I originally read it as wanting to show the standard circular order is continuous but it seems, from what you said in the comments, that is not what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose such a $c$ to be continuous. Note that means that the 3-torus without the fat diagonal is at least two connected components. How can we see that?

First, instead of trying to imagine a 3-torus, imagine three, possibly with multiplicity, marked points (which are colored/distinguished from each other) on the circle $S^1$ which will correspond to a point in $\mathbb T^3$. So if you "visually" see only two or one marked point that means that some marked points are overlapping (two coordinates are equal) and so is a point in the fat diagonal $\Delta$. Lets call the marked points $r,b,g$ and placed at $-1,i,1$ in $S^1$. It should be clear that you can not move the marked points so that $r,b,g$ are $-1,-i,1$ without crossing the fat diagonal.

It should also be clear, with this interpretation, that the components are fixed by the $S^1$ action, so $c$ can assigns the connected components a single value hence the function is continuous.

Comment: This is a place to start (as asked for) and how to think about it. My answer is of course not a full proof but it has the ideas of how to approach it.

Comment: I do not understand your argument quite well. I didn't understand this line, "So if you "visually" see two or one marked point that means that is a point in the fat diagonal Δ." and from your last paragraph, "with this interpretation, that the components are fixed by the $S^1$ action". Can you please explain it further. I have added the diagram to the original post after what I have understood from your suggestion.

Comment: @mathwizard If you move the marked points around so that two overlap that corresponds to two coordinates being equal, so you would be in the fat diagonal (not seeing a third point on the circle). The $S^1$ action is just rotation of the circle, and choosing three points on the circle and rotating gives a path from one point in the component to another point.

Comment: Also your picture isn't quite right, a single point in the torus corresponds to three points (with multiplicity) on the circle

Comment: Yes picture is not right. Thanks. I am wondering how do we utilize those two conditions (1) and (2) of function $c$  to prove its continuity in the sense you have interpreted it ?

Comment: @mathwizard Maybe I should say that there is more than one $c$ that works and some of them can be discontinuous (due to discontinuous isomorphisms of $S^1$—which use choice) but there is an obvious one to choose based off what I said (using the components). So I guess the actual correct answer is you can choose and find a $c$ to be continuous.

Comment: I am supposed to prove the continuity of general  $c$ satisfying condition (1) and (2) or just provide a counter-example that there exists such a $c$ which is not continuous. If there is any scope on mathstackexchange, may I ask for the complete proof based upon your argument or just a possible counterexample.

Comment: @mathwizard My comment explains/hints at how to find a discontinuous $c$ and my answer explains how to find a continuous $c$. "**I am** supposed to prove continuity..."  Why do you want me to provide a full proof then? Do you know the definition of continuity? Do you know what it means to be continuous when the target is discrete? If you have a discontinuous isomorphism of $S^1$ how might you define a (discontinuous) $c$?

Comment: Can you describe any circular order on the circle? If you can you should be able to show if it is continuous or not.

Comment: I asked my question for any such general $c$. I didn't ask for any specific continuous $c$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100660/discussion-between-mathwizard-and-paul-plummer).